# How to can i drag and drop cross tags in browser using javascript or jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

It look like Google search by images
Not only images but also selected text,...
Give me some simple example
thanks!

Comment: Take a look at [this](http://jqueryui.com/demos/draggable/)

Answer (score 2):

Go to [jQuery UI "Draggable + Sortable"](http://jqueryui.com/demos/draggable/) and watch the "Draggable + Sortable" which is very closely to something you want to accomplish

Answer (score 1):

is this what you need?
http://jqueryui.com/demos/droppable/